# How to understand VIM configuration noremap <leader>M mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm

Tags: vim

I find many results on internet using this confiuration to remove ^M. I can understand the substitute command `:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>`. But I cannot figure out why mmHmt and 'tzt'm is necessary.

```
noremap <leader>M mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mmHmt:%s/<C-V><cr>//ge<cr>'tzt'm
^^................................ create mark m
  ^............................... move the cursor to the top of the window
   ^^............................. create mark t
                          ^^...... move the cursor to mark t
                            ^^.... position the current line at the top of the window
                              ^^.. move the cursor to mark m
```

Creating those marks and jumping back to them after the substitution seems to be an attempt at keeping the cursor in place.

Hints:

- The mapping is a normal mode mapping so the commands in the RHS are assumed to be normal command by default.
- `mmHmt` is thus a sequence of normal mode commands, and so is `'tzt'm`.
- Doing `:help m` explains `mm` and `mt`. It also explains `'t` and `'m` indirectly.
- You are left with `H`: `:help H`, and `zt`: `:help zt`.

See `:help m`, `:help H`, `:help '`, `:help zt`.

---

Learning Vim is really easy. It not only allows one to understand random snippets found on the internet but, *more importantly*, to not need those in the first place.

See `:help user-manual`.